# How to calculate percentage of Grandtotal?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have table with duplicate values.
What I want to is calculate percentage of each row of grand total but I struggle with fixing denominator ignoring the filter and summarize distinct values (the denominator changes when I use filter or wrong number.

Below is the dax I use. How can I do? Many thanks.

```
% Grandtotal =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Combine Payroll + Payout'[SBS] ),
    DISTINCT ( 'Combine Payroll + Payout'[EMP&KEY] )
)
    / CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Combine Payroll + Payout'[SBS] ),
        ALL ( 'Combine Payroll + Payout' )
    )
```

[image]

| Employee_ID | Month_report | Key | Emp&key | SBS |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00004 | 01/10/2022 | 102022 | 00004102022 | 500000 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 00004 | 01/09/2022 | 92022 | 0000492022 | 600000 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 00004 | 01/08/2022 | 82022 | 0000482022 | 500000 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 00010 | 01/10/2022 | 102022 | 00010102022 | 400000 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 00010 | 01/09/2022 | 92022 | 0001092022 | 600000 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 00010 | 01/08/2022 | 82022 | 0001082022 | 800000 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 00010 | 01/07/2022 | 72022 | 0001072022 | 900000 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 00013 | 01/08/2022 | 82022 | 0001382022 | 600000 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 00013 | 01/07/2022 | 72022 | 0001372022 | 700000 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Here is the result i got after using your dax. The percentage fix when i use filter. I join with another table to get division information
[image]
[image]

Below is the data model

[image]

and data from the table I get division

|  | Job code | Division |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4.1603 | BOD |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 5.0195 | TRS |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 4.0695 | ESC |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | 4.0674 | RSB |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | 4.0684 | ESC |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 6 | 5.2303 | BTS |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 7 | 5.0676 | RSB |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 8 | 4.0679 | RSB |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 9 | 5.0687 | ESC |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Result update:
[image]

Comment: Can you give some more information about the fields you are using as it is not clear in image

Comment: I add 1 more image to the post. The table I use is by month so I create customed column to make it unique value: EMP&KEY (combine duplicate employee_id and month&year report). I want to sum total value in column SBS. Thank you.

Comment: Don't add sample data as images but [markdown tables](https://tableconvert.com/markdown-generator).

Comment: @Peter I change sample data to markdown tables as you recommend.

Comment: what does Combine Payroll mean? you used it as a column argument inside sum.

Comment: @OzanSen its the name of table: Combine Payroll + Payout

Comment: From your question you want to calculate the % Grand total, but allow it to do the total for the selected items? You can change ALL to ALLSELECTED, that should do it

Comment: @Jon I tried ALLSELECTED but it change according to the Filter. I want it fix the percentage.

Comment: @OzanSen Thank you for your response. I tried your dax, but the result is not true. 
I dont know how to add the image to this comment :(

Comment: Hi @ToanDang. Click the 'edit'  on the lower left corner of your post, and add the image and do whatever change you would like to do! and please tell me how you slice and dice your table. (what are the column names on the row of the matrix)? Stay safe!

Comment: @OzanSen i have added information to the post. Please reply if u need more information. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that you are slicing by a column [Divison] from a different table. It changes the game! Please share the image of your data model, and data from your 2nd table also.

Comment: @OzanSen I add the information you need. let me know if you need more information. Thank you.

Comment: @ToanDang Please check my updated solution. Please also check that your model is not ambiguous. (For filter context to choose the right path to reach its destination)

Comment: @OzanSen the result seem to be the same when I use the previous dax. I add new result to the post.

Comment: OK, thanks! I try to think for some other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your Model is more complex that I thought after seeing your data model. I made a small change in the code: My aim is to move the filter context from [OMS]_JOB_INFO_FOR_POWER_BI_MASTER_COST --> to Combine Payroll + Payout, traversing the immediate table: Please test this and let me know :)

```
% Grandtotal =
VAR TblSummary =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE (
            'Combine Payroll + Payout',
            '[OMS]_JOB_INFO_FOR_POWER_BI_MASTER_COST'[Division]
        ),
        "Total", CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Combine Payroll + Payout'[SBS] ) ),
        "%Percent",
            DIVIDE (
                CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Combine Payroll + Payout'[SBS] ) ),
                CALCULATE (
                    SUM ( 'Combine Payroll + Payout'[SBS] ),
                    ALL ( 'Combine Payroll + Payout' )
                )
            )
    )
RETURN
    SUMX ( TblSummary, [%Percent] )
```